# HTTP request with PHP CURL and getting different result from postman and curl cli

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to make a GET request using curl in php with the code below.

test.php

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://apiaddress/collection',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Authorization: Bearer 374dad6fdc005a0f17c49aeg77rbifuy48t7205hfhf7he8857c'
    ),
    CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => true
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

$info = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo "Response code: " . $httpCode . "\nResponse body: \n" . $response . "\n";
}


curl_close($curl);
echo $info;
```

This request works in Postman and works using this curl command `curl -X GET \
  https://apiaddress/collection -H 'Authorization: Bearer 374dad6fdc005a0f17c49aeg77rbifuy48t7205hfhf7he8857c'`, but when I run `php test.php` in the cli I get this output.  I'm guessing I'm missing a header or sending an incorrect header somewhere?

> Response code: 401
>
> Response body:
>
> {"type":"https://apiaddress/errors#error-unauthorized","title":"Unauthorized","detail":"No
>   authorization credentials provided. You must provide an authorization
>   token for this request.","status":401}
>
> GET /collection HTTP/2
>
> Host: apiaddress
>
> Accept: */*
>
> Authorization: Bearer 374dad6fdc005a0f17c49aeg77rbifuy48t7205hfhf7he8857c

Comment: What does `$info` contain?

Comment: `$info` is the output above that starts with GET

Comment: I too suspect it's an issue with the headers, why not compare the two? You may need to specify `Content-Type` in your PHP request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that this API requires the User-Agent header and it seems that Postman and the curl cli send those automatically while the php-curl request doesn't.  As soon as I added that header and made up a value it started working.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be running this under `localhost`, where you'll additionally need the line:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

This tells cURL not to verify your SSL certificate.

Alternatively, if you do indeed have a `.pem` certificate file, you can use:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/path/to/cacert.pem");
```

Comment: I set that flag and it still didn't work.  I also hosted the `test.php` file on an apache server with php and php-curl installed and the same thing happens.